# Laravel vue files requiring hard-refresh even when caching implemented

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

this issue has been plaguing my large production website for a while now.

My app.js (compiled by webpack) has multiple Vue components in it:

```
Vue.component(
    'product-import', 
    () => import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "product-import" */
        './components/product_import/ProductImport.vue'
    )
);
```

Whenever I add a new component to this file, and push my code to production... every single Vue module appears blank. The only way to solve this issue is to either:

1: Every user hard refresh the browser's cache (Ctr, Shift, R)

2: Rename EVERY SINGLE vue componenets (let's say from `<clock></clock>` to `<clock2></clock2>`) referenced in every file on my website.

I have versioning enabled `mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app2.js').version();`

And I've even tried renaming the app.js file, yet each time I add a new component it requires a hard refresh from every one of our users for them to be able to see **any** Vue module again on our site.

This deters me from adding new Vue components, as I have to rename every single component (and sub-component) referenced in all files. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Do you have cloudflare etc. Infront of your server?

Comment: I do not. This error is able to produce on my local server as well